# SharePoint 2013 - Custom Alert me form in Blogs

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

For **SharePoint 2013 blogs alert me**, I need to develop a custom form with less options as shown here. Another reason to go for custom form is better UI.

[image]

Current thoughts:
1. Develop a dynamic form using Bootstrap as user clicks on custom alert button
2. Using JSOM to make an entry in alerts

Question - Is it possible to make entry using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## My research till now:

- http://sitename/_vti_bin/alerts.asmx doesn't have add/update methods.
  It has just view & delete methods.
- One of the blog published in 2013 says alert doesn't support Client
  object model.
  http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/09/17/client-object-model-doesnt-support-creating-sharepoint-2013-alerts/
- Technet Discussion
  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/43d801d4-0e89-4ec5-9d6c-b36f8106fc0d/how-to-create-and-delete-alerts-using-client-object-model-or-even-web-services

## Learn about Alerts

- Alert web-service
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb249933.aspx
- Alert methods
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcalerts.alerts_methods
- Calling web-service using JavaScript
  https://weblogs.asp.net/jan/calling-the-sharepoint-web-services-with-jquery

## Conclusion

- From above data, it doesn't seem possible to achieve custom form for alerts using CSOM.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **Custom Action** to hide or overwrite the default ribbon button  Alert Me.

Create an Application page with you custom logic/forms and use a new Custom Action to Show this forms

Comment: Thanks for replying. I was looking for Client Side solution. Is there anyway I can avoid WSP?

Comment: You can use the JSOM (Javascript SharePoint Object Model) but I never use it. Check this links : [Add and Modify User Custom Actions Using JavaScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/hh185004.aspx) or a blog post : [How to include User Custom Actions and Scriptlink using SharePoint JSOM](http://aaclage.blogspot.fr/2013/12/how-to-include-user-custom-actions-and.html)

Comment: Thank you for replying. http://sitename_vti_bin/alerts.asmx doesn't provide add & update methods.